Expected url status code is 200 but in cloudflare workers fetch call for same url is giving 301
response headers of backend url
HTTP/2 200 
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=3600
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
etag: "4c94e079d45218460e7c0db2d010abfba3a4cff229547fcdeb2d6059333310"
last-modified: Wed, 11 Oct 2023 05:24:20 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31556926
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Tue, 06 Aug 2024 16:07:20 GMT
x-served-by: cache-bom4743-BOM
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1722960440.785547,VS0,VE269
vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
alt-svc: h3=":443";ma=86400,h3-29=":443";ma=86400,h3-27=":443";ma=86400
content-length: 25601 

I want to proxy my requests without exposing backend URL
www.frontend.com/login?queryParams -> www.backend.com/login?queryParams
these are response headers after deploying cloudflare worker on this route
 HTTP/2 301 
date: Tue, 06 Aug 2024 16:09:59 GMT
content-length: 0
location: https://www.backend.com/login
cf-ray: 8af04b640ee63217-BOM
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
retry-after: 0
accept-ranges: bytes
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 0
x-served-by: cache-bom4751-BOM
x-timer: S1722960600.703772,VS0,VE0
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\s=CeseREkv7hOLD9aXW6iL8G9oYh6nSUkSyp5DnEjnw4mTXM3CTN%2F7ppgZ%2BdJYdBjwH5edvop1ztV7SWEKm6bMtBRHq5o0eKetmrvG%2Bc3x7Dtb%2FfIjA%2BJPCg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}

see above response headers show its a permanent redirect
my wrangler.toml

```
name = "fronted-to-backend-proxy"
main = "src/index.ts"
compatibility_date = "2024-07-29"
compatibility_flags = ["nodejs_compat"]
routes = [
    { pattern = "www.frontend.com/login", zone_name = "company_domain.com"},
    { pattern = "www.frontend/refer", zone_name = "company_domain.com"},
]
```

index.ts
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx): Promise<Response> {
        // Parse the incoming request URL
        const url = new URL(request.url);

        // Define the URL patterns and their corresponding proxy endpoints
        const proxyMappings: { [key: string]: string } = {
            "/login": "https://www.backend.com/login",
            "/refer": "https://www.backend.com/refer"
        };

        // Check if the URL pathname matches any of the specified patterns
        if (proxyMappings[url.pathname]) {
            // Modify the URL to point to the new endpoint
            const proxyUrl = new URL(proxyMappings[url.pathname]);

            // Append query parameters to the proxy URL
            url.searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
                proxyUrl.searchParams.append(key, value);
            });

            // Create a new request with the modified URL, including headers and session
            const modifiedRequest = new Request(proxyUrl.toString(), {
                method: request.method,
                headers: request.headers,
                body: request.body,
                redirect: request.redirect
            });

            // Fetch the modified URL and return the response
            return fetch(modifiedRequest);
        }

        // If no match is found, return a 404 response
        return new Response("Not Found", { status: 404 });
    }
} satisfies ExportedHandler<Env>;

frontend.com is subdomain configured with cname <>
backend.com is also a subdomain configured with A record
both have flexible ssl configured in cloudflare
Any suggestion is much appreciated.


backend.com is also a subdomain


both have flexible ssl configured in cloudflare

This is the problem. When you set Flexible SSL, Cloudflare connects to your origin server using HTTP, not HTTPS, even when you specify HTTPS in the URL. The back-end that you are connecting to is receiving the request over HTTP, and is returning a 301 redirect to HTTPS, in an attempt to force the client to use HTTPS instead.
This "flexible" behavior applies to any hostname within your zone (your domain). It does not apply to requests sent to other domains.
You will need to change your SSL mode to "Full" or "Full (strict)" in order to tell Cloudflare to use HTTPS to talk to your backend. If this would break other origins that you have under the same domain, you may need to move the backend to its own separate domain / Cloudflare zone.
